# How exactly does the coordinate system work in Blender shader?

Tags: materials, shaders, shader-nodes, mathematics, vector-mapping

I am trying to understand how the Blender coordinate system works in shader.

So I create a plane with this simple shader:

[image]

I tried to move the coordinate origin point with a vector math node to the right, and this what happened:

[image]

I thought it would go to the right.

What exactly happened?

Another thing:

What will happen to the origin point when I use noise texture instead of one value?

[image]

Comment: You are not moving the object in this case, but the center for the mapping, which is why it is shown to you this way. But please try to ask only one question per post, so that a clear answer can be given. One question, one answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The origin… Of the confusion

I wanted to say how ***everyone else is wrong***, but that would be way too pedantic, maybe even misleading, like saying a hole doesn't exist, because it's not made of matter – and yet you can still fall into it.

Or another analogy: some people claim you can exceed the speed of light, because you can point a laser at one side of the Moon, and suddenly move it to the other side:

[See how to break the “cosmic speed limit” of light by using a laser](https://www.britannica.com/video/185489/Animation-speed-of-light-laser)

The moving dot is only an illusion, though.

Let's come back to Earth: in Blender there's a common misconception that you somehow operate macroscopically on data, like moving the entire coordinate system, or brightening an entire image. Meanwhile this is not what actually happens; your node tree is compiled into a program, and this program is run for each sample of a ray. So, pedantically speaking, **those statements are actually false**:

> ❌ You are […] moving the […] center for the mapping

> ❌ what you do with your node setup is moving the origin of your texture coordinate system to the right.

> ❌ The texture itself is placed

> ❌ the texture moved to the left

> ❌ the average effect will be to move the whole coordinate field

I can't stress this enough; all above statements are **also true on some level**. The problems appear when you overinterpret those statements and take them too literally. Like when a biologist uses words "purpose" and "goal", and creationists quote it as a confirmation of a designer, while those terms are only figures of speech describing how an organism changes due to a gene, benefits from it, and therefore the gene outcompetes other genes.

### What actually happens

You design your node tree. Blender parses it, and compiles it into a shader code – roughly speaking (I'm not that fluent on Blender source), each node becomes a function, and links between nodes represent which function's returned value is passed to which function as an argument (input). Then the code is uploaded to the GPU, and then when the camera shoots rays, the code is run for each sample.

One of the GPU cores will be tasked to render the x=50, y=100 pixel of a 200×200 px render. A ray is shot from ${(50, 100)\over(200, 200)} = ({1\over4}, {1\over2})$ to figure out the color of the pixel on ¼ of the middle line:

[image] [image]

The shader program is run, with all necessary input data passed to it—here it's just the ray hit position in the object (local) space:

`pos.xyz = -0.5, 0, 0`

`pos` is then passed as the surface color, and xyz components are interpreted as rgb; negative values are clamped to 0, so it's just a black color.

What if you add $0.7$ to your x component?

$$(-0.5, 0, 0)\\+(0.7, 0, 0)\\=(0.2, 0, 0)$$

`pos += 0.7, 0, 0`

So now the `pos` variable represents this spot:

[image]

But here's an important thing: the code on GPU still runs processing the pixel x=50, y=100. You didn't move; you simply changed a variable. If you reinterpret it as RGB, this time you end up with a dim red color…

And what happens when you sample a texture?

If you used *Generated* coordinate space, the same camera pixel will have an input of:

`pos = 0.25, 0.5, 0`

And the sampled color will be some shade of red:

[image]

But if you add `0.25` to the x coordinate, you will sample a different point on the texture:

[image]

Remember, you're not actually changing which camera pixel you're processing. You can only change which texture pixel you're sampling. So you're not moving `0.25` to the right, you're moving something being `0.25` to the right of you, to self (to the currently processed pixel). Repeat it for all pixels and [it looks like] the texture moved:

[image]

Comment: simply ... wonderful ... puts everything in the shade ... this is how you correct scraps of words when you have a clue about the subject matter

Comment: Thanks @Peter Mortensen! The "EVERYONE ELSE IS WRONG" part was supposed to capture an OCD character of pedantism ;) I'm going to study the links given in edit summary…  quellenform thanks for kind words, perhaps too kind ;)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning your first question: what you do with your node setup is moving the origin of your *texture coordinate system* to the right. The texture itself is placed such that the texture's origin is placed at the origin of your object. As the object's origin stays fixed (at 0,0,0) the texture moved to the left when you move its origin to the right. You get even more control if you use the "Vector -> Mapping" node, which allows translation, rotation and scaling.

You get a more intuitive result of your texture mapping if you switch the mapping type from default "Point" to "Texture". Then the texture coordinate will move to the right if you translate in the positive x-direction.

Concerning your second question: I believe (didn't look into the code of the "Noise" texture" node) the texture coordinate is calculated in a random way for every point on your plane, depending on the noise settings like granularity, detail, etc.

Answer (score 1):

*Noise Texture* -> *Color* outputs a random *positive* value between 0 and 1 on each color channel for every point on a mesh surface.  So the **average effect** will be to move the whole coordinate field in the positive direction by (0.5, 0.5, 0.5) while producing good local randomization.